# How to do array push in object wise using PHP

Tags: php, php-5.6

I have one array, in this array values, i want to push object wise,how can do this?

```
print_r($_POST['amenity_check']);
```

> Array
>       (
>           [0] => Gym
>           [1] => Swimming Pool
>       )

Expected Results

> "amenities": [
>           {
>                   "amenity_name":"Gym"
>           },
>           {
>                   "amenity_name":"Swimming Pool"
>           }
>           ],
>          ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
$output = [];
foreach ($_POST['amenity_check'] as $value)
{
    $output[] = [
            'amenity_name' => $value
        ];
}

echo json_encode([
        "amenities" => $output
    ]);
```

Output:

> {"amenities":[{"amenity_name":"Gym"},{"amenity_name":"Swimming Pool"}]}

This uses a `foreach` loop to get the desired output as array, and the uses `json_encode` to turn it into a json string.